# Difference between apt search and apt-cache search

Tags: apt

I'm not getting the same results when using `apt search` and `apt-cache search`: using `apt`, I'm getting a lot less results than using `apt-cache`. For example, searching for screenshot gets me 4 results with `apt` and 62 results with `apt-cache`. Moreover, `apt-cache` lists results which do not mention screenshot in the name or short description. Grepping for screenshot in the `apt-cache` search results filters the results to 12!

It seems `apt` is only searching package's name while `apt-cache` is searching the package's name and long description. But in this case, looking for a screenshot tool, the best result I get is the grepped `apt-cache search`!

I like using `apt search` as it is more convenient, but is there a way to make it behaves like `apt-cache`. Also is there a way to make `apt-cache` search only the package name and short description?

Comment: I get very different results! With both `apt search screenshot` and `apt-cache search screenshot`, I get 12 results of which 8 don't have `screenshot` in the package name itself. Have you enabled the Universe repository? I have. I'm on 16.04.

Comment: These are the packages: gnome-screenshot, gkrellshoot, gtk-vector-screenshot, kazam, 
kde-spectacle, 
kgrab, 
screenfetch, 
screengrab, 
screenie-qt, 
shutter, 
videocut, 
xfce4-screenshooter

Comment: Actually the initial results I got were from a Linux Mint box, I just realised I should've asked in another forum!  Doing the same test on a Ubuntu Mate 16.04 with universe repo enabled, I get 62 results from `apt-cache search` as in my mint box, and I also get 62 results with `apt search`, only differently formatted. Still I do not get the 12 results I would like, and that you obtained...!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you cannot filter `apt-cache search` but I have found a way that could function similar to what you want.
 Type `sudo nano .bashrc` and add the line `alias apt-search='apt-cache search'` to the end of the file. There are few limitations though:
1. You cannot use `sudo` before typing `apt-search` in the command line. It will tell you command not found
2. Can't override the apt search name. Bash will not allow it.

This will be applied when you logout and log back in. Hope this helped.

Comment: I did thought about using aliases, but was hoping for another way, like maybe a config file or command line switches... thanks anyway!